# Install GDAL for ubuntu 18.10

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, 18.10

When I try to install `gdal`, I get the following error:

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository is for Ubuntu **bionic** while, according to your title, you're on Ubuntu **cosmic**.

As it seems there's no `cosmic` release for the PPA (yet?), you should try with the `xenial` version, but it's not guaranteed to work.
It should be enough to edit the relevant `.list` file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and change `bionic` to `xenial`:

```
#deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

That said, looks like `gdal` is present on the [official Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/gdal-bin), so maybe the PPA is not really need.

Comment: Installed using official Ubuntu repositories and it worked. Thanks